# how to get id from android xml without using findviewbyId method in java class

Tags: android

I am using 2 java class in my android project, one class to get id from android xml & another class for performing the activity. I dont know how to access the second class to get id from first class.

Comment: do you mean classes or activities?

Comment: TextView tv=(TextView)context.findViewbyId(R.id.textView01);

Comment: this findViewById can be used in first class for getting id and how can i access it in the second class without using findViewById method

Comment: if my answer was useful and true, set it as the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a helper class for the activity and you want the helper class to have access to the view hierarchy. Just pass the activity instance to the helper class when you create an instance of it. It can then use `findViewById` to find the view(s) of interest.

Answer (score 1):

you can't access.

when your first java class is foreground you can access Views which  is showing on the screen

but when another activity is foreground why do you wanna access background activity Views that is not visible.???

**But**

you can add a method in first activity input the id and return the object

like this:

```
View getView(int id) {
   return getViewById(id);
}
```